# Getting 'gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever' while combining python3.4, flask and gevent

Tags: python-3.x, flask, gevent

I am getting this error once I have gevent imported in my project. I don't need to actually make call to touch any gevent code and get this error automatically every time I make a call through Flask API. Any ideas?

I used this version of gevent:

```
pip install git+git://github.com/ddxd/gevent.git
```

Here is the error messsage:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 617, in process_request_thread
self.finish_request(request, client_address)
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 673, in __init__
self.handle()
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 203, in handle
rv = BaseHTTPRequestHandler.handle(self)
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 398, in handle
self.handle_one_request()
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 234, in handle_one_request
self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline()
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 374, in readinto
return self._sock.recv_into(b)
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 282, in recv_into
self._wait(self._read_event)
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/_socket3.py", line 97, in _wait
self.hub.wait(watcher)
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 359, in wait
result = waiter.get()
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 586, in get
return self.hub.switch()
File "/home/qa/anaconda3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 349, in switch
return greenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: This operation would block forever
```

Answer (score 0):

I disabled debug mode and it fixed the issue. Not sure why it could happen though.
This post seems to be related.

https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/Flask-SocketIO/issues/66

Comment: Careful, gevent (and flask-socketio) are not yet supporting python3, you might solve this problem, but may very well have more issues in the future.